How made OxyPlot DPI awareness in wpf?
I have a wpf app DPI aware with this code in the manifest filed:
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/PM</dpiAware>
        <!--<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>-->
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2,PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
        <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>

I'm using OxyPlot.Wpf to making some plot, but how can I made for the plot to be the same with any monitor and DPI configuration.
For example:
enter image description here
enter image description here
In the left pictures the resolution is 1920x1080 with a escale of 100% and in the right pictures the resolution is 2880x1800 with a scale of 175%.
The pictures on the right are deformed. The triangle must be equilateral triangle and the pentagon also with all of theirs side equals.
How can made to be like the pictures on the left with any monitor?
Do I have to install OxyPlot.SkiaSharp.Wpf package?

The problem was that my MainWindow (the container of the PlotView) has a LayoutTransform:

Me.Scrll.LayoutTransform = New ScaleTransform(ScaleX, ScaleY)

So, I put to the PlotView:

Plot.LayoutTransform = New ScaleTransform(1 / ScaleX, 1 / ScaleY)

And with that the plots are not deformed in both monitors.
